# Insert data into mysql using dataflow

Tags: python, mysql, google-cloud-platform, google-cloud-dataflow, apache-beam

The below code builds the pipeline and DAG is generated. 
RuntimeError: NotImplementedError [while running 'generatedPtransform-438']Please let me know if there is any direct connector for mysql in python for beam.

```py
from apache_beam.options.pipeline_options import PipelineOptions
from google.cloud import pubsub_v1
from google.cloud import bigquery
import  mysql.connector
import apache_beam as beam
import logging
import argparse
import sys
import re


PROJECT="12344"
TOPIC = "projects/12344/topics/mytopic"    

class insertfn(beam.Dofn):
def insertdata(self,data):
db_conn=mysql.connector.connect(host="localhost",user="abc",passwd="root",database="new")
db_cursor=db_conn.cursor()
emp_sql = " INSERT INTO emp(ename,eid,dept) VALUES (%s,%s,%s)"
db_cusror.executemany(emp_sql,(data[0],data[1],data[2]))
db_conn.commit()
print(db_cursor.rowcount,"record inserted")
class Split(beam.DoFn):
def process(self, data):
data = data.split(",")               
return [{ 
'ename': data[0],
'eid': data[1],
'dept': data[2]         
}]

def main(argv=None):

parser = argparse.ArgumentParser()
parser.add_argument("--input_topic")
parser.add_argument("--output")
known_args = parser.parse_known_args(argv)


p = beam.Pipeline(options=PipelineOptions())

(p
| 'ReadData' >> beam.io.ReadFromPubSub(topic=TOPIC).with_output_types(bytes)
| "Decode" >> beam.Map(lambda x: x.decode('utf-8'))
| 'ParseCSV' >> beam.ParDo(Split())
| 'WriteToMySQL' >> beam.ParDo(insertfn())
)
result = p.run()
result.wait_until_finish()
```

Comment: What is the error message you are getting?

Comment: I am examining your code. Since you are new to Apache Beam programming I would suggest you to see this repository for python DataFlow codes created by Google, [link](https://github.com/GoogleCloudPlatform/professional-services/tree/master/examples/dataflow-python-examples/dataflow_python_examples). Another thing, did you define your **Split()** process the same way as **insertfn()** ?

Comment: Can you tell me the version of Apache Beam you are using? Also, you mention the above code runs, do you mean your MySQL is on prem? Can you also tell me the commands you used to run the pipeline?

Comment: @AlexandreMoraes I use the apache beam 2.19.0.the command to run pipeline is python -m npipe   --input_topic "projects/myprojectid1/topics/mytopic"   --streaming     i dont use on prem mysql ,i wrote separate python file just to insert some random hardcoded values into cloud mysql and it worked,so i suspect issue is where the pipeline code connects to mysql instance.please let me know your thoughts

Comment: add additional information while posting questions.

Comment: ok sure .my basic question now is that is'nt possible to connect to cloud sql as sink for dataflow using python?do we have to opt for java only?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After our discussion in the comment section, I noticed that you are not using the proper commands to execute the DataFlow pipeline.

According to the [documentation](https://cloud.google.com/dataflow/docs/guides/specifying-exec-params#configuring-pipelineoptions-for-execution-on-the-cloud-dataflow-service), there are mandatory flags which must be defined in order to run the pipeline in [Dataflow Managed Service](https://cloud.google.com/dataflow/docs/guides/deploying-a-pipeline). These flags are described below:

> - **job_name** **-** The name of the Dataflow job being executed.
> - **project -** The ID of your Google Cloud project. runner - The pipeline
> - **runner -** that will parse your program and construct your pipeline. For
>     cloud execution, this must be DataflowRunner.
> - **staging_location -** A Cloud Storage path for Dataflow to stage code packages needed by workers executing the job.
> - **temp_location -** A Cloud Storage path for Dataflow to stage temporary job files created during the execution of the pipeline.

In addition to these flags, there are others you can use, in your case since you use a PubSub topic:

> - **--input_topic**: sets the input Pub/Sub topic to read messages from.

Therefore, an example to run a Dataflow pipeline would be as follows:

```
  python RunPipelineDataflow.py \
  --job_name=jobName\ 
  --project=$PROJECT_NAME \
  --runner=DataflowRunner \
  --staging_location=gs://YOUR_BUCKET_NAME/AND_STAGING_DIRECTORY\
  --temp_location=gs://$BUCKET_NAME/temp
  --input_topic=projects/$PROJECT_NAME/topics/$TOPIC_NAME \
```

I would like to point the importance of using [DataflowRunner](https://beam.apache.org/documentation/runners/dataflow/), it allows you to use the Cloud Dataflow managed service, providing a fully managed service, autoscaling and dynamic work rebalancing. However, it is also possible to use [DirectRunner](https://beam.apache.org/documentation/runners/direct/) which executes your pipeline in your machine, it is designed to validate the pipeline.

Comment: thank you for the information ,this time I was to able to execute the pipeline .It progressed till running state after which it failed with the message  "Caused by: java.lang.RuntimeException: Error received from SDK harness for instruction -43:" I edited the same code to write to bigquery instead of  mysql using beam.io.WriteToBigQuery and it was successful. I see that a recent mysql beam connector is released but i am not able to use this.Any suggestion? https://pypi.org/project/beam-mysql-connector/

Comment: @anonymous1, could please edit your question with the code you are currently using? So I can dig deeper in the issue.

Comment: @lexandre Moraes I have edited as per your suggestion .do we have to write  custom transform to connect to mysql via beam

Comment: @anonymous1, I just saw that you posted a different error in the question.Where is the generatedPtransform function in your code?

Comment: yes,now the code is throwing this error.my code is not having generatedPtransform function .my question is that is my approach to insert the values to mysql correct?

Comment: Are you still getting the error described in you question? You approach seems correct.

Comment: yes ,i get the error. i tried using the beam io mysql connector WriteToMySQL .then the error changes to cannot connect to mysql on localhost(99)